# When I say "no further recommendations" is plural use of recommendations correct?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

"We have no further recommendations for this dataset at this stage."

or

"We have no further recommendation for this dataset at this stage."

Does the "no" necessitate the use of recommendation rather than recommendations?

Comment: Depends on the context.  Is the recommendation good/bad/mediocre, or are there recommendations you might make about changes to the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

For the meaning that applies in the present case this word is both countable and uncountable. This is the meaning in [OALD, 2](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/recommendation?q=recommendation), repeated below for convenience.

> [uncountable, countable] the act of telling somebody that something is good or useful or that somebody would be suitable for a particular job, etc.

You can therefore choose the uncountable option and add no s or choose the countable option, but then either an s  is necessary or, for the singular, a slight modification (We don't have a further recommendation…).

The adverb "no" is not determining in the choice of using a plural form or a form without s. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=15&smoothing=3&content=no+further+recommendation%2Cno+further+recommendations&year_end=2008&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20further%20recommendation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20further%20recommendations%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cno%20further%20recommendation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20further%20recommendations%3B%2Cc0)); however, if no s is used it might not be clear whether "recommendation" is countable or not; if the context in what precedes does not make that clear, one possibility is as good as the other.

Of course, this way of deciding whether to use s or not is valid for all such nouns; you only need to check the particular noun in OALD or some such dictionary that makes precise whether a noun is countable, uncountable, both, or else.

Comment: Isn't the choice between singular count and plural count? "We have no car[/s] suitable for a driver of your capabilities at present, Mr Hamilton"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It seems the three choices are possible; "further" does not preclude the use of an uncountable noun: for instance with "notice" (only uncountable) the phrase "no further notice" (used often) shows that.

Comment: Certainly. But (1) a dictionary showing (one assumes correctly) that a word is used in both count and non-count usages does not guarantee that both are always available (*There was a coffee all over my chair.) and (2) in this case, I think singular or plural usages only make sense. Non-count: "average change in broker recommendation is always preferred over ...".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Unfortunately for me, I fail to grasp the subtleties you are referring to. I can see that instead of the usual "There was coffee…" the rare "There was **a** coffee…" gives a more precise idea of the mess. I don't follow you on that question of availability. Would it be the case that not all contexts are pliable to uncountable use? Neither can I see how lengthening the bulk of a "packet" of recommendation could not make sense.

Comment: The asterisk before a sentence labels it as ungrammatical. *'There was a coffee all over my chair.' Though 'There was a coffee on the table' is fine. A dictionary would perhaps label _coffee_ << [noun] [uncountable, countable] >> but that doesn't license a free choice in all contexts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see, but there is an important point to keep in mind: whereas for the **same** meaning of "recommendation", a single word, we have both the countable and the uncountable possibility, it isn't so for the form "coffee"; there are really two words, "coffee" as countable **and** uncountable (roasted seed) and "coffee" as the only countable word (portion of prepared coffee).

Comment: I repeat. (2) in this case, ("We have no / 1 further recommendation // some / 3 further recommendations for this dataset at this stage.") I think singular or plural usages only , not a non-count usage, make sense.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Then, could you explain why "There'll be no further notice…" (uncountable) makes sense whereas "We have no further recommendation…" does not. I have no reason telling me that, no logical argument to convince me.

Comment: The very fact that OP is quite reasonably asking for a judgement call between the  choices 'recommendation' and the plural form here show that a count possibility is very possible. A similar statement would be 'We have no further enquiry/enquiries about your product.'  But 'notice' is often non-count: 'Notice was given that ...'. Rarely 'Enquiry was made about' and perhaps equally rarely 'Recommendation was made that'. Would you use 'Further recommendation was made that ...'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd hesitate to use that, it seems to belong to the no man's land that exists in the territory of the English passive voice; however, there is no absolute countercheck: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=further+recommendation+was+made&corpus=15&year_end=2008&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfurther%20recommendation%20was%20made%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Most (all but two of the ones not needing opening) of those are the count usage 'a further recommendation was made'